# Multiple rom booting

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, dual-boot, multirom-manager

Is there any way to dual boot on the international GT-n7000 phone ?
I have no tried the CWM backup / restore to switchbetween two ROMs but I would guess no issue with that to be encountered. Just that it would be too cumbersome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is extremely complex and (in my opinion) not material for SE since there are a lot of files that you'd need to download and cannot be hosted here. Fortunately, XDA has a thread for [multi-booting on the GT-N7000](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1748588). I also found this [tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6JU08mONHY) so that you can see how its done.